# Irrational number check function

Tags: python, math

I am trying to graph the following function:

```
f(x) = 0 if x is rational else 1 # so 1 if x is irrational
```

My plan is to use python and matplotlib. How do you generate random irrational numbers in Python?

Comment: Your graph is just 2 things that look entirely like lines; there are infinitely many rational and irrational numbers in any given range.

Comment: There is no concept of irrational numbers in programming, as nothing is infinite.

Comment: @minion91 I do not entirely agree. You cannot represent irrational numbers in a floating point representation, but it is possible to represent and manipulate irrational numbers (as well as infinite quantities) within mathematical software.

Comment: Helpful: ["it is impossible to draw the function properly, because we should draw two horizontal lines, but not quite lines"](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txtb/4/txe3ba4s.htm), which includes what your graph will look like...

Answer (score 12):

This is called [Dirichlet function,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function#Dirichlet_function) and it's example of function that nowhere continuous. It's a simple mathematical fact, between any pair of numbers, there is infinite number of rational and infinite irrational number.

Plotting this function in practice is equivalent to plotting *f(x)* = 0  and *f(x)* = 1, as you're plotting using discrete pixels.

There are two gotchas:

- even though Python uses [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), it's only capable of representing rational numbers;
- in the set of real numbers there is [continuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum) of irrational numbers and only [aleph-zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_zero#Aleph-naught) rational numbers. Thus probability that any random number is irrational is 1;

Either way, this kind of "problem" is not meant to be approached as strictly programming problem.

Comment: Also, there are infinitely more rational numbers than irrational numbers! Which means if you were plotting `n` "random" numbers, they'd all be irrational... :)

Comment: I suppose that we could also argue that *every* number that is stored in a computer is rational since the precision is limited.  (even with "infinite precision" libraries, eventually you run out of memory).  So maybe it's just equivalent to plotting `f(x) = 1`, even though there are infinitely more irrational numbers as pointed out by @hayden ;-)

Comment: @hayden: actually, between each pair of rational numbers, there is infinite number of irrational numbers...

Comment: @vartec yes that's true. However, the rationals are countable, the irrationals aren't! (hence infinitely more irrationals than rationals :) )

Comment: @hayden: right, but you got that just the opposite in your first comment, there are more irrational than rational numbers.

Comment: @vartec True! Of course I meant "there are infinitely more IRrational numbers than rational numbers". Whoops!

Comment: +1, but I think this statement should be clarified: "It's only capable of representing rational numbers".  As written, that's not true.  I use Python to work with irrational, and even transcendental, numbers all the time in symbolic form.

Comment: @DSM: I mean, that symbolic math is not part of Python language nor core library. Of course you can use 3rd party library, which represents irrational numbers. Still, only limited number of them.

Comment: @vartec: but you can only represent a limited number of *rational* numbers too, so that doesn't distinguish them.

Comment: +1, but some corrections. #1, *Python uses arbitrary-precision arithmetic*, I can make Python use continued fractions, and voila! irrationals. #2, *it's only capable of representing rational numbers* No matter how you represent numbers, Python (or any other language on a realizable computer) is only capable of representing a finite number of numbers. #3: *Thus probability that any random number is irrational is 1*: To be pedantically correct you should have said *almost certainly* is 1. In fact, a random number almost certainly is not a computable number.

Comment: @DavidHammen: "probability that any random number is irrational is 1" isn't about Python representation, but about set theory in mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is you can't.

What you can do is figure out some epsilon after which this number is considered irrational.

It will look the same.

consider this: square root of 2  is an irrational number.

wolframlpah gives you an approximation : 
1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480...

python only sees 
1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480
which means:
1+ 4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480/
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: An epsilon after which a number is considered irrational, really? As stated above, there are rational and irrationak numbers between any two numbers. Can you explain in what way your suggestion makes sense?

Comment: None of the numbers rand() will produce is irrational. So it will never be accurate. However you may decide rational numbers ends in 99999/100000. There are enough numbers to still draw the graph the way it should. Obviously it will make no mathematical sense.

Comment: Or even better some kind of mod operation

Answer (score 3):

A random number is irrational almost always (i.e. withprobability 1)

```
def f(x): 
    return 1
```

works almost always as you want!

Comment: A more appropriate function would be `def (x): return 0`, since any value that can be represented in a numeric type in python is rational.

Comment: "hironical" isn't a word, and "histrionic(al)" doesn't mean funny.

Comment: I think he means "ironic". It's OK to have funny answers, as long as they are also correct. The downvoters must have found the other answers to be more accurate than this one.

Comment: Indeed my answer is correct: A random number (say from 0 and 1)is irrational almost always. As far as maths are not an opinion... 

hironical was a sort of typo as well as 'hirionical' in verdesmarald comment

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?source=search_app#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=1&tok=YrlL4lPySgLJ9Dur0utCfw&pq=ironical&cp=20&gs_id=3u&xhr=t&q=lebesgue+measure+of+rational+numbers&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=lesbegue+measure+of+&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=9e8bc36898b2283e&biw=1104&bih=736

Comment: But your function does not return a random number between integers n and m. It returns a specific integer. Even if you chose it randomly, you either chose an integer or a rational number. I dare say neither of us knows how to randomly choose an irrational number, let alone represent it in Python. Even assuming you could, it still does not answer the question, which revolves around generating irrational number, not numbers which may be irrational. At the very least, you'd also need an algorithm to check irrationality.

Comment: However, as I already explained in my first comment, an implementation of `f` in any system which represents numeric values as finite sets of bits *must always return 0*, since `n` must always be rational in such a system.

Comment: @delnan the ironical part actually is the following: 
If you want to iteratively get x = random_real_number() and y =f(x) so to plot x vs y, the fastest way is to always take one as ordinate. That's the funny part of my answer. But I'm the only one finding that's funny! I apologize.

Comment: @verdesmarald: "any system which represents numeric values as finite sets of bits"?

Comment: @verdesmarald I cannot give an example, but I would not bet my argument on a finite implying the only numbers you can represent are rational. Sure, you cannot represent all irrational numbers in finite bits as there are infinitely many, but that's not the question (and also true for natural numbers, integers, and rational numbers). And there may be ways to represent certain irrational numbers in a useful way.

Comment: @delnan Sure, I overgeneralised there. For example you could say any pattern where the top bit is `1` represents `e * <the rest of the bits>` or some other silly mapping. What I meant was that, in general, a real numeric argument to a computer function is always going to be rational, since the schemes for interpreting bit patters as real numbers in common use only allow representing some finite subset of the rational numbers.

Comment: It is funny. Almost always. Haha

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that you cannot represent an irrational number in a computer program. It doesn't fit into memory, you cannot print the whole irrational number, but you can still do some calculations with them and do operations like "give me the first 100 digits". You can represent them as a kind of lazy enumerator. The problem is, that this does not really fit your needs because checking if this kind of number is rational is equivalent to the halting problem and hence undecidable.

But choosing an irrational number in an interval, e.g. between 0 and 1 is not always impossible, it just depends on what you want to do. I recently did that, but the application of those numbers just that they had to be compared and some decisions of the algorithm depended on the these comparisions. Here, representing them as lazy enumerators works fine: If you compare, you start on the left side and compare each digit until one number has a larger digit. So we just generate random digits on the fly and store the generated digits in an array until they are different from the corresponding digit of the number we are comparing to.

Just to make the difference clear between a finite number and an infinite number for which we only need a finite part: In the first case, the length of the number is fixed and bounded, in the second case, we only have to store a finite number of digits, but this number may grow beyond any bound, so every finite number is different from such an infinite number, if we compare enough digits.